# Database Connection Error with Logstash

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logstash

I am trying to connect to database to extract data from sql with logstash; and my server name is WIN-07LLQEN2SJB\SQLEXPRESS. When I run the logstash configuration file, it returns database connection error. Would like to ask if anyone have ideas towards it. Great Thanks in advance.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/WIN-07LLQEN2SJB\SQLEXPRESS;user=sa;password=*****"
    jdbc_user => "sa"
    jdbc_password => "*****"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT database_id, name, data_used_size, log_used_size FROM DISK.dbo.disk_activity"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
    jdbc_page_size => "50000"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch_http {
    host => "localhost"
    index => "sql"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the host name and port where your DB runs?

Comment: The host name should be WIN-07LLQEN2SJB and the port should be 1433 as for default. I have tried to turned off the firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx), I think the `jdbc_connection_string` should be

```
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://WIN-07LLQEN2SJB\SQLEXPRESS:1433;user=sa;password=*****"
```

Comment: Woulld you also like to take a look at this? [collect network operation data with logstash windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537373/collect-network-operation-data-with-logstash-windows)

Comment: hello Mr Val, woukd you mind to take a look at here please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67918094/logstash-sqlserver-jdbcadapternotfound-could-not-load-jdbc-mssql-adapter-adap thank you